# Find next and preview child elements from child element click

Tags: jquery, html

I saw many questions almost similar like this, but I couldn't find a solution.

I want that, when I click on `target` class, to find other next `target` class. Here is what I've done so far, but it doesn't seem to work.

Thank you in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.target').click(function(){
     if ($(this).parent().next().is('.target')) {
        var link = $(this).parent().next().is('.target');
        console.log(link.text());
     }
   })
})
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li>
      <div class="image-here"></div>
      <div class="target">First description</div>
   </li>
   <li>
     <div class="image-here"></div>
      <div class="target">Second description</div>
   </li>
    <li>
      <div class="image-here"></div>
      <div class="target">Third description</div>
   </li>
    <li>
       <div class="image-here"></div>
       <div class="target">Fourth description</div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `$(this).parent().next()` will point to sibling of parent `li`, Can you elaborate What do you need?

Comment: I want from child element to find next child element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.target').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).parent().next('li').find('.target').text());
    console.log($(this).parent().next('li').find('div').hasClass('target'))
    if($(this).parent().next('li').find('div').hasClass('target')){//true if there is next parent li with div with class name target
      
    
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="image-here"></div>
    <div class="target">First description</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="image-here"></div>
    <div class="target">Second description</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="image-here"></div>
    <div class="target">Third description</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="image-here"></div>
    <div class="target">Fourth description</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Use `.find()` after getting the next li to get the element with class `target`

Comment: You are right, but I need that condition. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: a condition to ?please clarify a bit sorry i need more info.. what condition do you want?

Comment: I will explain more, look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zQUhV/47/. I have another code structure, like I described in snippet, and the paragraph like in the fiddle. But when I put my code structure, I cannot find next and prev element.

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi glad to help mate happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `next()` element will be `<li>` and doing `.is('.target')` you are checking if `<li>` has class `.target`. I think it's better to do `.find('.target')` instead of `.is('.target')`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.target').click(function() {
    var nextParent = $(this).parent().next();

    if (nextParent.length) {
      console.log(nextParent.find('.target').text());
    } else {
      console.log('End of line');
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="image-here"></div>
    <div class="target">First description</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="image-here"></div>
    <div class="target">Second description</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="image-here"></div>
    <div class="target">Third description</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="image-here"></div>
    <div class="target">Fourth description</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I need that condition, I want to check out if there is the right next target.

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi Check update. It would be `nextParent.length > 0`

Comment: I already found a solution,  thanks for trying to help! Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would have done:

```
$('.target').click(function() {
 console.log($(this).closest("li").next().find(".target").text());
})
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dvfbhr9y/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.parent()/.closest()/.parents()` to find the parent of the current clicked element and use `.next()` to find next element and `.find()` to find your target

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.target').click(function(){
        console.log($(this).closest("li").next().find('.target').text());
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li>
      <div class="image-here"></div>
      <div class="target">First description</div>
   </li>
   <li>
     <div class="image-here"></div>
      <div class="target">Second description</div>
   </li>
    <li>
      <div class="image-here"></div>
      <div class="target">Third description</div>
   </li>
    <li>
       <div class="image-here"></div>
       <div class="target">Fourth description</div>
   </li>
</ul>
```